# Add an icon/image to beside text as a part of a menuItem in PopupMenu

Tags: java, awt, system-tray

I am creating a small program for my system tray in which it gives some information and displays an icon in the popup menu beside text. I have tried to add an icon using the JMenuItem but then I cannot add it the PopupMenu. Nor if I use a menuItem I cannot add an icon.

Here is my code so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

//......


public class Interface 
{
    public static void mainInterface()
    {
        if(!SystemTray.isSupported())
        {
            System.out.println("System tray not supported! This program can only be used on Windows.");
            return ;
        }
        SystemTray systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/icon.png");

        PopupMenu trayPopupMenu = new PopupMenu();

        MenuItem close = new MenuItem("Close");
        MenuItem CMItem = new MenuItem("test1", new ImageIcon("src/greenIcon.png"));
        MenuItem HerItem = new MenuItem("test2", new ImageIcon("src/greenIcon.png"));


        close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                System.exit(0);             
            }
        });
        trayPopupMenu.add(close);
        trayPopupMenu.add(CMItem);
        trayPopupMenu.add(HerItem);
        TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Status", trayPopupMenu);

        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);

        try
        {
            systemTray.add(trayIcon);
        }catch(AWTException awtException)
        {
            awtException.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("end of main");
    }
}
```

The above code will not run because of the icon portion in the menuItem objects. Can someone help me with putting the icon beside the text in the menu?

Edit:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The constructor MenuItem(String, ImageIcon) is undefined
    The constructor MenuItem(String, ImageIcon) is undefined

    at minecraft.status.checker.Interface.mainInterface(Interface.java:23)
    at minecraft.status.checker.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:12)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the stack trace you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of `MenuItem` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/MenuItem.html), `MenuItem` does not have a constructor that can take an icon (that's what your stack trace is saying, too), nor does it support any methods to add any icons. In short, `MenuItem` can't take an icon.

You mentioned trying to use javax.swing's `JMenuItem`, but as you discovered, a `JMenuItem` would require a `JPopupMenu`, which isn't supported by `TrayIcon`. Because there isn't any `JTrayIcon` or other similar counterpart to `TrayIcon` for Swing, I don't believe it's possible to do what you're attempting.

Comment: Interestingly, in [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/systemtray.html) article it seems like it's possible to add icons to menu items with AWT.

Comment: May using https://github.com/dorkbox/SystemTray could do the trick.